# Android ImageView ontouch

Tags: android, imageview

I want to implement body part selection in android. My requirement is, when I tap on specific part the image app should be able to identify the body part and color of the selected part should change.Attached a sample image for reference.

Any idea or suggestion at the earliest would be very much appreciated.[image]

Comment: You need to fix X and Y limits for each part. In `onTouch`, check which part the coordinates of the touch fall in.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal- Do you have any example/link to share

Answer (score 0):

In your input, set x,y position each part of body.

Then you can calculate nearst part of touch x,y with simple code.

Or more complex, you can set rect.

In visual part, you can add another imageview overlay original image.

If your image is separated, you can use

```
imageView.setColorFilter()
```